# How prove this usefull identities with equations

Tags: analysis

> let $f(x):R\to R$ be $C^{k+1}$, show that
>   $$\left(\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d}{dr}\right)^{k-1}\left(r^{2k-1}f(r)\right)=\left(\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d}{dr}\right)^k\left(r^{2k}\dfrac{df}{dr}\right),k=1,2,\cdots$$

This problem is from  Lawrence C.Evans-Partial Differential Equations,P.90

he say this is clear,But I don't know why this is clear,and I try prove this found this not only no clear,but also I can't prove it for me .so How prove it?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It easy follows from induction on k:

Basis: $k=1$:
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\right)(rf(r))=2\frac{df}{dr}+r\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}=\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)\left(r^2\frac{df}{dr}\right).
$$

Step: from k to k+1:
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^{k}\left(r^{2k+1}f(r)\right)=
\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)\left(r^{2k+1}f(r)\right)=\\
\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^{k-1}\left((2k+1)r^{2k-1}f(r)+r^{2k}\frac{df}{dr}\right)=\\
\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^{k}\left((2k+1)r^{2k}\frac{df}{dr}+r^{2k}\frac{df}{dr}+r^{2k+1}\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}\right)=\\
\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)\left(r^{2k+2}\frac{df}{dr}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\right)^{k+1}\left(r^{2k+2}\frac{df}{dr}\right)
$$
We used induction hypothesis in 3rd "=" to functions $(2k+1)f(r)$ and $r\cdot df/dr$.